# when run composer update following error occurs how can i fix it please help

Tags: magento2

[ab17d226@cloudhost-61966 html]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

- The requested package amasty/product-attachment 2.1.0 exists as amasty/product-attachment[1.2.6, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.5, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2] but these are rejected by your constraint.

**Problem 2**
    - The requested package amasty/base 1.5.0 exists as amasty/base[1.6.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.9, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4.1, 1.4.10, 1.4.2, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.9, 1.5.3, 1.5.5] but these are rejected by your constraint.